What are the most important evaluation metrics for anomaly segmentation?
When people talk about anomaly segmentation models, they often mention evaluation metrics like F1 score, AP, AUROC, and AUPRO. But which one really matters most when comparing models, and why? I'm skeptical about the pixel-level F1 score, as it might not give us the full story since there are always going to be lots of false positives and negatives at pixel level. When we're looking at anomaly maps, what seems more important is the big picture—the overall clusters of anomalies. So, my main question is: which metric best reflects how well a model is performing overall?
